# How do I run a task created by a plugin in gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle, gradle-plugin

I've written a gradle plugin that adds a custom task called `generateTestDocs`, which depends on the task `groovydoc`, which itself is created by the `groovy` plugin.

```
//MyPlugin.groovy
@Override
void apply(Project project) {
    project.apply(plugin: 'groovy')
    project.task(type: GenerateTestDocsTask, dependsOn: ':groovydoc', 'generateTestDocs')
}

project.tasks.groovydoc.doFirst {
    println "I should see this message but I don't"
}
```

I'm trying to test this plugin by running the task `generateTestDocs`

```
@Test
void testRunGenerateTestDocs() {
    Project project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
    project.apply(plugin: 'my.gradle.plugin')
    project.tasks.generateTestDocs.actions*.execute(project.tasks.generateTestDocs)
}
```

For the last line in my test, I'd like to instead just say `project.task.generateTestDocs.execute()` and have it run the task with all of its dependencies, but that doesn't seem to work.  The documentation for writing gradle plugins only shows assertions like `assertTrue(project.tasks.hello instanceof GreetingTask)` which shows the task is added to the project, but doesn't show how to run that task.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Programatically invoke a gradle task graph in a unit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264966/programatically-invoke-a-gradle-task-graph-in-a-unit-test)

Comment: Nevermind, found my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264966/programatically-invoke-a-gradle-task-graph-in-a-unit-test

Answer (score 0):

`ProjectBuilder` is only meant for unit tests. To run a build as part of a test, you'll need to use the Gradle tooling API, or a third-party plugin such as [nebula-test](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-test) (which builds upon the tooling API).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same question,  I solved this by add

> apply plugin: CustomPluginName

in current gradle.build :

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
...
// in this case Plugin name is MyPlugin
apply plugin: MyPlugin
```